# Matlab plot in histogram

Tags: matlab, statistics

Assume `y` is a vector with random numbers following the distribution `f(x)=sqrt(4-x^2)/(2*pi)`. At the moment I use the command `hist(y,30)`. How can I plot the distribution function `f(x)=sqrt(4-x^2)/(2*pi)` into the same histogram?

Comment: Aren't you already plotting it with `hist`?

Comment: The rough idea is to call hist with two outputs, so it gives you bin centers and counts.  Then you manually bar plot these, and superimpose a scaled density function on top of the bar plot.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of normalizing numerically, you could also do it by finding a theoretical scaling factor as follows.

```
nbins = 30;
nsamples = max(size(y));
binsize = (max(y)-min(y)) / nsamples
hist(y,nbins)
hold on
x1=linspace(min(y),max(y),100);
scalefactor = nsamples * binsize 
y1=scalefactor * sqrt(4-x^2)/(2*pi)
plot(x1,y1)
```

Update:  **How it works.**

For any dataset that is large enough to give a good approximation to the pdf (call it f(x)), the integral of  f(x) over this domain will be approximately unity. However we know that the area under *any* histogram is precisely equal to the total number of samples times the bin-width.

So a very simple scale factor to bring the pdf into line with the histogram is Ns*Wb, the total number of sample point times the width of the bins.

Comment: This answer doesn't have enough context on its own. Can you improve the answer to be self-contained?

Comment: I thought the calculation of the "scalefactor" was fairly clear from the code provided. However I can add some more details of **why** this particular scale factor works. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example of another distribution function, the standard normal.  To do exactly what you say you want, you do this:

```
nRand = 10000;
y = randn(1,nRand);
[myHist, bins] = hist(y,30);
pdf = normpdf(bins);
figure, bar(bins, myHist,1); hold on; plot(bins,pdf,'rx-'); hold off;
```

This is probably NOT what you actually want though.  Why?  You'll notice that your density function looks like a thin line at the bottom of your histogram plot.  This is because a histogram is counts of numbers in bins, while a density function is normalized to integrate to one.  If you have hundreds of items in a bin, there is no way that the density function will match that in scale, so you have a scaling or normalization problem.  Either you have to normalize the histogram, or plot a scaled distribution function.  I prefer to scale the distribution function so that my counts are sensical when I look at the histogram:

```
normalizedpdf = pdf/sum(pdf)*sum(myHist);
figure, bar(bins, myHist,1); hold on; plot(bins,normalizedpdf,'rx-'); hold off;
```

Your case is the same, except you'll use the function f(x) you specified instead of the normpdf command.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add another example to the mix:

```
%# some normally distributed random data
data = randn(1e3,1);

%# histogram
numbins = 30;
hist(data, numbins);
h(1) = get(gca,'Children');
set(h(1), 'FaceColor',[.8 .8 1])

%# figure out how to scale the pdf (with area = 1), to the area of the histogram
[bincounts,binpos] = hist(data, numbins);
binwidth = binpos(2) - binpos(1);
histarea = binwidth*sum(bincounts);

%# fit a gaussian
[muhat,sigmahat] = normfit(data);
x = linspace(binpos(1),binpos(end),100);
y = normpdf(x, muhat, sigmahat);
h(2) = line(x, y*histarea, 'Color','b', 'LineWidth',2);

%# kernel estimator
[f,x,u] = ksdensity( data );
h(3) = line(x, f*histarea, 'Color','r', 'LineWidth',2);

legend(h, {'freq hist','fitted Gaussian','kernel estimator'})
```

[image: hist]